# How to change color of dropdown items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to change a color of dropdown items , my code is down.

In this case i want to change color of Dr. Winthrop, Dr. Chase, Dr. Sanders.

Here is a HTML/Bootstrap code.

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> About <span class="caret"></span> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dr. Winthrop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dr. Chase</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dr. Sanders</a></li>
                        </ul>                    
                    </li>
```

I tried this, but not working.

```
ul dropdown-menu li{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: I am new here, now I edited my question, and I wrote what i have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li a{
color:red;
}
```

Next time include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
    //css here
}
```

Comment: This would change all `li a`. OP only want to change dopdown-menu ones.